# emacs replaces a remote (gvfs/sftp) symbolic link with a regular file when saved

Tags: emacs, symlink

Environment: GNU Emacs version 23.2.1 on Ubuntu Lucid.

I have a remote filesystem mounted locally using Gnome's gvfs/sftp protocol. Upon editing a remote file via its symlink (also remote), and then saving it, emacs replaces the remote symlink with the edited copy of the target file. The target file is untouched.

```
local:~/remote/prakash/tmp> ln -sv ../.bashrc
./.bashrc' -> `../.bashrc'

local:~/remote/prakash/tmp> ls -l ./.bashrc ../.bashrc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 prakash prakash     9 2011-06-13 16:29 .bashrc -> ../.bashrc
-rwx------ 1 prakash prakash 10269 2011-06-13 16:29 ../.bashrc

# ... Editing and saving ~/prakash/tmp/.bashrc in emacs ...

local:~/remote/prakash/tmp> ls -l ./.bashrc ../.bashrc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 prakash prakash 10270 2011-06-13 16:30 .bashrc
-rwx------ 1 prakash prakash 10269 2011-06-13 16:29 ../.bashrc
```

As can be seen above, the link to `../.bashrc` was replaced by a copy of the edited file and the target file is unmodified.

Searching for `symbolic-link` and `symlink` via `apropos` didn't turn up anything useful.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does this happen if you edit the file with something else, or just with Emacs?

Comment: Can you see if this behavior can be reproduced if you used TRAMP?  I couldn't reproduce it using Emacs 23.3.1 on Debian testing/unstable here.

Comment: @jeremiahd: you are right. It seems to be the artifact of how the files were presented to local system by gnome-vfs. The same thing happened when I edited and saved the symlinked file in vim.

Comment: Since this is no longer emacs related question, I would like to close the post. Or should I delete it altogether?

Comment: It turns out that this is due to a gnome-vfs bug (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=584348). Sorry for casting aspersions on emacs and wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by a gnome-vfs bug: [GVFS Symbolic Links are Destroyed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=584348), and has nothing to with emacs.